# Access Directories of remote server with PHP

Tags: php, django, remote-server

I am trying to upload files from my remote server to an s3 bucket. The catch is that I am accessing this server from localhost. While using PHP upload functionality in my django templates, it gives a list of files in my local directory. I would like it to give me the directories in my server.

Is there anyway I can change the domain name of this php functionality to match my server's domain name? If yes, how?

I am currently trying to find a backdoor mechanism like weevely that could connect with my server.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>`
```

Select image to upload:

TIA

Comment: _"While using PHP upload functionality in my django templates"_ - What? That sentence doesn't really make much sense. Do you mean that you have the upload form (HTML) in a django template which _submits_ the form to a PHP script?

Comment: yes! @MagnusEriksson. Thats exactly it

Comment: Am I correct in that you want to show files on the server instead of files on their local machines when users clicks "Browse" to pick a file for upload? If that's the case, you can't use a standard HTML file-input. You would need to build something that fetches all the files and folders and present them for the user.

Comment: Can you give me some direction to what needs to be done? I am pretty new at this

Comment: I'm afraid that the question is a bit too broad. Basicall, you would need to add a button, then when someone clicks it, you need to fetch the files/folders on the server (Using Ajax or similar). Then you need to list them for the user somehow and also build the action when someone selects a file. I can't really be more specific since I don't know nearly enough about your setup.

Comment: Yea sure that would help! Thanks again